Antenna complex input impedance into real impedance
I'm trying to design a loop antenna and make it resonate around 100 MHz.
Using a standard 50 ohms port, the resonating frequency is not at 100 MHz. Since I cannot change the geometry, I'm going to change the input impedance from 50 ohms to the complex conjugate of the Z11 I see at 100 MHz. In this way I get the correct resonance.
Through post processing I can change the real input impedance into complex impedance. My question is: does it exist a mathematical way to convert the complex impedance into real impedance to match the resonating frequency (or at least around that frequency)?
I'm asking that, because any EM software (HFSS, CST or other) does not allow a complex impedance to a port, but only real ones

You don't change the 50 ohm input impedance of the receiver to a complex value, you change the output complex impedance of the antenna to 50 ohm. And, of course there are ways of doing it but, your question is really rather weak and unclear in details.

The term you're looking for is "matching".

Usually when you desing an antenna you define the input impedance (but you can see it also as output if you wanna see it from the receiver). In these software, to fed the antenna you need to define a port (lumped, wave port or whatever) and it is asked the port impedance (the input impedance). I know I can use a matching circuit to move from 50 ohms to the complex conjugate I need to make it resonate (and this is what I do through PP by math and not capacitor or inductors). In these software, port impedance cannot be complex. Hence my question if is possible to convert it (not matching)
